# How do I store static core data of my app?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently creating a monster collecting game like Pokemon. There will be like 100 monsters there. I am confused on how should I store the monsters' static core data, like initial HP, icon, etc. It doesn't make sense to store them in DB and retrieve the data every time I switch to another activity because those static data won't change.

I have been thinking of some solutions:

1. Using a static class. Something like:

   ```
   public class StaticClass {
       public String[] name = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...] // 100 entries
       public int[] initialHP [100, 200, 300, ...] // 100 entries

       // name[i], initialHP[i] would be the identity of i-th monster
   }
   ```
2. Retrieve JSON from DB just once, and then save the data into SharedPreferences.

I honestly think that both approach aren't good. First approach would require a lot of writing, and the other would save a quite big data into SharedPreferences. I am pretty sure there would be a much better approach.

Comment: What about `SharedPreferecnes`? They are much simpler in use and easier in implementation.

Comment: Use sqlite to achieve that

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris OP is finding more easier solution than sqlite(DB).

Comment: What dou you mean by OP , do you mean SharedPreferences?

Comment: > "First approach would require a lot of writing" — not true, you can generate the code by other code.

Comment: Any way you are right SharedPrefereneces is much more easier than Sqlite

Comment: Pokémon Go used Couchbase https://blog.couchbase.com/pokemon-go-scaling-profile-services-with-couchbase-nosql/

Comment: @jackjay Whoops my bad, I have edited my question. I really meant the 2nd approach as saving it into SharedPreferences. It would be too stupid to just passing it using bundle lol. 

I agree that it's much easier using SharedPreferences, but is it fine to store a list of 100 monsters into that?

Comment: @Lutaaya An actual database makes more sense than a simple XML file that SharedPrefences is

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris OP ---> Original Poster or the person who post this question. OP is used to refer that person.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't make sense to store them in DB and retrieve the data every time I switch to another activity because those static data won't change.

I beg to differ. Your best bet (and fastest) is to store it in SQLite db.

To make things easier for yourself, make a separate class for DB related work. Additionally, you can use any [third-party SQLite DB browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to manually make a DB. You can then easily ship that pre-made SQLite db and ship it as an asset. Upon app installation this db will be set-up, as a one time process. Use this very useful helper: [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

If you just do not want to ping the DB again and again, you can retrieve all this data in a global `arrayList` at app launch. To create this fully global `arrayList`, make a new class `MyApplication.java` that extends `Application`. Init your `arrayList` in the `onCreate()` method of this class.